# Undefined element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

I'm trying to build a simple AJAX POST. It consists of a username and a password. The username element in my html remains undefined after the user has submitted the data. What could be the problem. Here is my code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#form").bind('click', function (event) {

                alert(username = $("#username").val())
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post("/main3/",

                username = $("#username").val(),

                function (data) {

                    alert(data);

                    $('#content').html(data)

                })
                return false;
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">Name
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        </br>Age
        <input type="text" name="age" />
        </br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

I have included the whole page for reference. My server is Django.

Comment: Are you trying to declare a variable inside the $.post function, where the data normally goes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an element with an id of `username` in your code. You have an input element which has a **NAME** of `username`. name is not the same as id.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
                  ^^^^^^^^^^--missing
```

Comment: or use attribute selector $('input[name="username"]')

Comment: You were right. I didn't have the username ID. I put it in and it worked fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the parameter incorrectly, pass it as an object, and use a correct selector for the element you want to select to get its value (there is no element with id username)

```
$.post("/main3/", {username: $("[name=username]").val()},
```